# Element-wise compound assignment operator in Julia

Tags: julia

Consider the following two functions,

```
function f(x)
    x = x .+ 1
end

function g(x)
    x .+= 1
end
```

My understanding is that they should behave identically, since `a .+= b` is just syntactic sugar for `a = a .+ b`. However `f` does not mutate a global variable passed to it as an argument, while `g` does.

Can anyone explain to me what is going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: My guess based on what you said is that when you do `x = x .+ 1` it is creating a new `x` object vs when you do `x.+= 1` it utilizes the existing object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *almost* right: `x .+= 1` is syntactic sugar for `x .= x .+ 1` which does in-place elementwise assignment whereas `x = x .+ 1` rebinds `x` to the new array produced by doing elementwise addition.

Comment: Interesting, so there doesn't actually exist any syntactic sugar for `x = x .+ 1`?

Comment: No, there’s no shorter version of that.